# How to set UIDatePicker's date's seconds value to 00?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, uidatepicker

How to always get seconds value "`00`" for  `UIDatePicker`'s date?

Now I am getting value like this format `5:30:45`, I need to get this format of time `5:30:00`.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSDate *currentDate = [datePicker date];    
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
NSString *Str_Seccond=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
```

In Str_Seccond string you can get the seconds in string format.

Answer (score 14):

I used this code it is working fine.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit ) fromDate:datePicker.date];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) fromDate:datePicker.date];

    [dateComponents setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    [dateComponents setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
    [dateComponents setSecond:0.0];

    NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```

Comment: Kudos to you -- it's clear that none of the other respondents understood the question.  I've got the same issue: the date picker is showing only hours and minutes, yet it's returning non-zero seconds.  7:55:59 is NOT the same thing as 7:55, and the extra 59 seconds are messing up subsequent calculations.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to juggle with the NSDateComponents or convert the date to a string and back. You just can tell the calendar to set the date to the beginning of the minute (hour/date/week/…)

```
NSDate *date = self.datePicker.date;
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitMinute
                                startDate:&date
                                 interval:NULL
                                  forDate:date];
//date now is set to the beginning of the minute -> seconds == 00
```

Comment: NSMinuteCalendarUnit depreciated in iOS 8. Do you have any replacement method to achieve the same thing ?

Comment: `NSCalenderUnitMinute` maybe?

Comment: according to `NSCalendar.h`, auto completion should tell you: `NSMinuteCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_4, 10_10, 2_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitMinute instead") = NSCalendarUnitMinute`

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4 version :

```
 let calendar = NSCalendar.current
 let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day,
                                           .hour, .minute], 
                                           from: yourDate)
 let date = calendar.date(from: components)
```

Comment: Your answer is missing `.month` in the components.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"ss"];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateformatter stringFromDate:[datePicker date]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute], fromDate: datePicker.date)
let date = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)
```